# Capybara visit always gives me error 404

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, capybara, http-status-code-404

I am doing some modular Sinatra app and making tests with rspec and Capybara. The problem is that I always get 'Not found' error 404 when trying to visit a page. When I use the command 'bundle exec rackup' and go to the same url but in the browser everything is ok. Here's my spec:

```
    require "spec_helper"
    require_relative '../../routes/user_routes'

    set :environment, :test


    RSpec.describe RubyPlay, type: :feature do
      include Rack::Test::Methods

      def app
        RubyPlay # this defines the active application for this test
      end

      before { visit '/' }
      it "should allow accessing the home page" do
        p page.html # prints Not found
        p page.status_code # 404
        expect(page).to have_content 'Ruby Play'
      end
    end
```

bundle exec rspec:

```
   RubyPlay should allow accessing the home page
   Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content 'Ruby Play'
   expected to find text "Ruby Play" in "Not Found"
```

I've never done tests in Sinatra and have no idea what might be wrong... :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution - I just had to add:

```
    Capybara.app = RubyPlay
```

to the spec_helper.rb file! Now it can find its routes...

Comment: Yes -- without setting the app Capybara doesn't know what to load/run --  in rails thats all handled when you include capybara/rails - but with Sinatra you need to do it manually